# SELECT FROM not working in node js with PG

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, view

I'm trying to retrieve some information from a Postgree SQL view in a Postgre SQL database. However, the result is always empty. When I execute the same query in the database, it gives me the expected results.

```
const privq = await db.query('SELECT * FROM user_privilege');
console.log(privq.rows);
//[]
const projectsQuery= await db.query('SELECT * FROM projects');
console.log(projectsQuery.rows);
//[{id:1,name:'Example Project',description:'Lorem Ipsum...'},
//{id:2,name:'Test Proj',description:'testing'}...]
```

It does not happen with other queries. The entity `user_privilege` is a view and not a table.

**UPDATE**

I verified the DB and it turns out Datagrip (my program to interact with the DB) was querying the OLD server, while node was querying the new one. The new one actually has no privileges at all, just the projects.

Comment: I speculate that an error is being thrown in the first case, but your code is just swallowing it.  Try to see if there is any error output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I checked after reading your comment. There seems to be no error in the output, just the empty array

Comment: Try using this query in your Node.js code: `SELECT * FROM blahblahblah` ... does this also not throw any error?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it says 'error: relation "blahblahblah" does not exist'

Comment: Then the only explanation I can see here is that your `user_privilege` view/table has no records.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right! I verified the DB and it turns out Datagrip (my program to interact with the DB) was quering the OLD server, while node was quering the new one. The new one actually has no privileges at all, just the projects.